# Complex Analysis Question: how to find x, y in relation to z, z bar

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to prove that the function: $f(z)= x^2-y^2+2ixy$ is not conformal. Another student suggested that I should use the following: $x = \frac{z+ \overline{z}}{2}$ and $y = \frac{z - \overline{z}}{2}$, to help guide me towards a solution, but we haven't been explicitly taught this yet. So how do we know that $x = \frac{z+ \overline{z}}{2}$ and $y = \frac{z - \overline{z}}{2}$?

Comment: Have you tried substitution $z=x+iy$ and run through the arithmetic?

Answer (score 0):

We have $$z=x+iy$$ and $$\overline{z}=x-iy.$$ Adding these we obtain
$$ z+\overline{z}=2x.$$
Similarly, substracting them we obtain
$$ z-\overline{z}=2iy.$$

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was a simple connection that I was missing.